# How to fix "ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_39 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (10, 2)"?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am new to Transfer learning and Cnn's,was just playing around with cnn and got this error.Tried many solutions but none of them works.

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras import backend as k
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import GlobalMaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.models import Model
from keras.applications import imagenet_utils
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

mobile = keras.applications.mobilenet.MobileNet()

#mobile.summary()
train_path = 'chest_xray/train'
val_path = 'chest_xray/val'
test_path = 'chest_xray/test'

train_batch = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input).flow_from_directory(
              train_path,
              target_size = (224,224),
              batch_size = 10)
test_batch = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input).flow_from_directory(
              test_path,
              target_size = (224,224),
              batch_size = 10,
              shuffle = False)
val_batch = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input).flow_from_directory(
              val_path,
              target_size = (224,224),
              batch_size = 10)

def prepare_image(file):
  image_path = ''
  img = image.load_img(image_path+file,target_size = (224,224))
  img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
  img_array_dims = np.expand_dims(img_array,axis = 0)
  return keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input(img_array_dims)


x = mobile.layers[-60].output
predictions = Dense(1,activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inputs = mobile.input,outputs = predictions)
print(mobile.input)
#model.summary()

for layer in model.layers[:-5]:
  layer.trainable = False

model.compile(Adam(lr=.0001),loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(train_batch,
                    steps_per_epoch=4,
                    validation_data=val_batch,
                    validation_steps=2,
                    epochs = 30)
```

I am using mobilenet for transfer learning and an error is spotted every time.None of the solutins seems to work.Tried playing with the Flatten() then 2dmaxpooling() but no results.

ERROR:

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-187-08820ea8d15a> in <module>()
      3                     validation_data=val_batch,
      4                     validation_steps=2,
----> 5                     epochs = 30)
```

Value-error: Error when checking target: expected dense_39 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (10, 2)

Answer (score 0):

The layer of the `MobileNet` at which you are chopping of (-60) is `conv_dw_5_relu` which has output dimensions `(None, 28, 28, 256)`. So you will have to flatten it before connecting a Dense layer to it.

#### Working code

```
mobile = keras.applications.mobilenet.MobileNet()

x = mobile.layers[-60].output
x = Flatten()(x)
predictions = Dense(2,activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inputs = mobile.input,outputs = predictions)
#model.summary()

model.compile(Adam(lr=.0001),loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(np.random.rand(10, 224, 224, 3), np.random.rand(10,2))
```